# Замена спецсимволов в столбце mysql

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Хотел использовать такую функцию

```
UPDATE `oc_url_alias` SET `keyword` = CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(`keyword`, '\\+|;|:|,|\\?|=|#|@|&|\\.|!|\\$|~|\\[|\\]|\\{|\\}|\\*', '-') AS CHAR) WHERE `keyword` REGEXP '\\+|;|:|,|\\?|=|#|@|&|\\.|!|\\$|~|\\[|\\]|\\{|\\}|\\*'
```

Но получаю ошибку так как нельзя использовать CAST и WHERE
Подскажите как можно решить данную проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Сделал вот так но пришлось исключить точку с запятой, из-за нее ошибку выдает

```
UPDATE `oc_url_alias` SET `keyword` = CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(`keyword`, '[^A-Za-z0-9/_-]', '-') AS CHAR) WHERE `keyword` REGEXP '=|:|\\+|,|\\?|=|#|@|&|\\.|!|\\$|~|\\[|\\]|\\{|\\}|\\*'
```